# Problem with fresh install wordpress

Tags: wordpress, error, install

I am doing a fresh install with CiviCRM civicrm-5.41.0
That is because my old host (Dreamhost) disallowed database triggers so I cannot upgrade on that site.

I am following the advice in the moving Civi to first do a fresh install.

The site is just running CiviCRM on WordPress and has no other content since it is a fresh install.  When I run the installer (https://website.org/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install) it is able to add tables to the WordPress database and populate at least many of the tables.  It does not, however add any triggers. It does add foreign keys.

Here is the error message - it says it cannot connect to the database, but it was able to add the tables and rows.

This error breaks WordPress.  I am not able to go back to the WordPress homepage or to the plugins page to disable CiviCRM. Deleting all the CiviCRM tables does not make the error go away. Deleting civicrm.settings.php does allow me to go back to the WordPress homepage.

The database address shown in the installer is something like:
mysql://wpe0a8b643ac11:HIDDEN@unix%28%2Ftmp%2Fmysql5.sock%29/madends_wpe0a8b643b6

Would Civi choke on the % parts of the string or the socket?

```
Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => simpleHandler
        )

    [code] => -24
    [message] => DB Error: connect failed
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] =>  [nativecode=php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] =>  [nativecode=php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: connect failed" code=-24 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info=" [nativecode=php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known]"]
)
```

Comment: The hosting support replied:

The plugin did not recognize the database connection settings correctly. We updated /home/website/www/directory/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php accordingly. CiviCRM seems to be installed and operational:

https://website.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM

You may have to finalize the setup. Let us know if there is anything else we can help with.

Better than average hosting support!  I guess those % constructions were the problm.